# Why we need push same image in many folder Android Project

Tags: android, project, drawable

I'm newbie in Android.
I see that, by default Android project contain many drawable folder.
What is problem if I only push image in xxhdpi.

Comment: My friend. you need to read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when android application run then your android project internally detect the device size

ldpi means 240 X 320 device resolution.
mdpi means 320 X 480 device resolution.
hdpi means 480 X 800 device resolution.

we can use these all different images better design our android application.
If you are use 9 patch image then does not required different images Because 9 patch have a quality to display all resolution devices.